# Error in Installing rjava package in R OS windows 7 32bit, R Version 3.1.2 , Platform i386-w64-mingw32, system:i386, mingw32

Tags: java, r

I am new to R, trying to install rjava package. already installed jre1.8.0_31 on R3.1.2 OS windows 7 32 bit.

set env variables as `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\` . also added

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\client\` to Path variable.

still showing following error while installing rjava package

```
installing *source* package 'rJava' ...
** package 'rJava' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rJava'
* removing 'D:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library/rJava'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"D:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "D:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\library" "D:/Coursera/rJava_0.9-6.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘D:/Coursera/rJava_0.9-6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

For me updating to a new version of R (from 1.3 -> 3.2 ) helped. You can try:

```
    # installing/loading the latest installr package:
    install.packages("installr"); library(installr) #load / install+load installr
     updateR() # updating R.
```